# Tagging system design issues

Tags: database, database-design, application-design

I'm working on a news site and I'm thinking of implementing a tagging system (similar to this site) where you'll be able to categorize news by different category types such as: newscategory (economy, politics, etc.) but also things such as language it was written in and type of news article (editorial, feature story, etc.).

How should I distinguish between these different category types? Should I have one table of tags for each category type, or should I keep everything in one table and have a tag-prefix such as "language:en", "category:economy"? The second solution seems more flexible because I can add more caregory types just by appending a prefix. However the first solution feels more structured and easier to work with.

Also, I wonder how you determine when something should be represented as a tag or when it should be a column value/record in the database (e.g. should the language be a tag or do I have language column in my "News" table?). I'm not sure where to draw the line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be sufficient to say that the tags themselves could be ordered in a hierarchy? If so, just add a `parent_tag_id` to your `tags` table.

```
id  name          parent_tag_id
-------------------------------
1   language      null
2   english       1
3   french        1
4   newscategory  null
5   economy       4
6   politics      4
```

You might think of columns as static fields and rows as dynamic. Keep the number of columns low. Language might be a column of all fields in the table should be associated with a language.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'm still leaning towards using seperate tables for each category type though. I might want to associate more things with the category types, the category types themselves does not necessarily have to be dynamic and I prefer the normalized structure.

Comment: If different category types are to have different property types and functionality, then maybe go for separate tables for each of them. If they all share the same properties, except for the names, then just create one table called categories.